# Magento Sort by “In Stock” in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, sorting

Can you please tell me how can Sort products thats are only "IN STOCK" by custom option on products listing page...

as for the lowest and highest price i am using this code...

```
 <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'asc') ?>" <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Lowest Price</option>
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('price', 'desc') ?>" <?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected" <?php endif; ?>>Highest Price</option>
```

What code changes should i do to show only products that are in stock by sort by option...

Should i have to create a custom attribute first or there will be any attribute already in the adminpanel...

If yes, what will be the attribute code.. please help me i need it on urgent basis.

Thanks in advance,,,

Answer (score 1):

To add a new custom sorting option, you need to

1) rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Config` and update method `getAttributesUsedForSortBy`

2) check if you new method is selected and update the product collection according to new option logic.

For example, [this module](http://amasty.com/improved-sorting.html) rewrites the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` and modifies `setCollection` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301841/filtering-product-collection-on-is-salable

More search results: http://goo.gl/TckAcm

Comment: I want to show an option in dropdown buddy.. is there any way... ??

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Please add some description or code snippets..